# How to deploy Spring Boot to Cloud Foundry?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I tried to deploy my spring boot app to CF with the following `pom.xml`

```
       <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**UPDATED**

My application

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EdollarApplication {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EdollarApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DataSourceConfiguration.java

```
@Configuration
@Profile("cloud")
public class DataSourceConfiguration {

  @Bean
  public Cloud cloud() {
    return new CloudFactory().getCloud();
  }

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(DataSourceProperties.PREFIX)
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return cloud().getSingletonServiceConnector(DataSource.class, null);
  }

}
```

There's no error in the logs however I am not able to access the URLs that I have defined in the application. Sample logs shown below

```
Updated app with guid 8b167ac9-11bb-483e-be0a-3dd8c8991a84 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
-----> Downloaded app package (20K)

-----> Downloading Open Jdk JRE 1.8.0_45 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/openjdk/trusty/x86_64/openjdk-1.8.0_45.tar.gz (2.5s)
       Expanding Open Jdk JRE to .java-buildpack/open_jdk_jre (1.3s)
-----> Downloading Tomcat Instance 8.0.21 from https://download.run.pivotal.io/tomcat/tomcat-8.0.21.tar.gz (0.5s)
       Expanding Tomcat to .java-buildpack/tomcat (0.1s)
-----> Downloading Tomcat Lifecycle Support 2.4.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/tomcat-lifecycle-support/tomcat-lifecycle-support-2.4.0_RELEASE.jar (0.0s)
-----> Downloading Tomcat Logging Support 2.4.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/tomcat-logging-support/tomcat-logging-support-2.4.0_RELEASE.jar (0.0s)
-----> Downloading Tomcat Access Logging Support 2.4.0_RELEASE from https://download.run.pivotal.io/tomcat-access-logging-support/tomcat-access-logging-support-2.4.0_RELEASE.jar (0.0s)
-----> Uploading droplet (51M)
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService           INFO    Starting service Catalina
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO    Initialization processed in 514 ms
[CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-61187"]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine            INFO    Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.21
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig             INFO    Deploying web application directory /home/vcap/app/.java-buildpack/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
[CONTAINER] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner               INFO    At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[CONTAINER] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol         INFO    Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-61187"]
[CONTAINER] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool         INFO    Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
[CONTAINER] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina               INFO    Server startup in 507 ms
```

What did I miss here ?

Comment: Probably worth confirming ... Is `EdollarApplication` in a root package called `demo`? And does it run on the command line? i.e. `java -jar <app>-<version>.jar`?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you don't need `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in your main class.

Comment: Is there any sample for `Spring Boot` to work out of the box or with minimum configuration in Cloud Foundry ?

Comment: It already works pretty much out of the box. Although I'm wondering now - given that you haven't shown one above, what does your `manifest.yml` look like?

Comment: I don't have a manifest.yml. Do I need one ?

Comment: Aha! I think we might have found the issue. I shall write a quick answer with an example Cloud Foundry manifest.

Comment: @abiieez, is the issue resolved, you were mentioning issue with accessing URLs, do you mean any GET url in the controller you are not able to access outside?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example of a minimal Spring Boot project which is configured to run in Cloud Foundry: https://github.com/gratiartis/super-mini

I got it running in Cloud Foundry by putting the following `manifest.yml` into the root directory of the project.

```
---
applications:
- name: super-mini
  # Fork of https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack
  # For stability, keep your own fork.
  buildpack: https://github.com/gratiartis/java-buildpack
  memory: 512M
  instances: 1
  # Because the URL will be http://super-mini.cfapps.io/
  host: super-mini
  domain: cfapps.io
  path: target/super-mini-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Note that the following can be added to activate a profile (i.e. "cloud"):

```
  env:
    SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud
```

The `path` is based on me running the deploy from the root directory of my project. As I'm sure you will have guessed, it's a Maven build, so a .jar is created in a `target` directory.

To deploy, `cd` into the root directory of the project and run:

```
cf push
```

The above will create an application running at http://super-mini.cfapps.io/hello

Take a look - it's running at the moment. Of course, I have now created that application name, so you can't use that!

Comment: Should I use mysql as the profile name like yours ? Or I need to change it to `Cloud` as in the `DataSourceConfiguration` above.

Comment: I followed exactly what you suggested. The application was pushed to the cloud however I am not able to access any of the urls. In fact in the logs I don't see any request mapping has been mapped.

Comment: Oh no ... I just have an `application.yml` in the application resources folder with a profile called `mysql`, which defines the connection details. It was an easy way to get it working, but the Spring Cloud stuff will probably be better.

Comment: Does it show application startup in the logs? They ought to provide some info on whether the app was deployed, what it was called, whether there were any issues during startup, etc.

Comment: Also, where is your application logging configured to go?

Comment: the application logging is only log to the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77076/discussion-between-abiieez-and-steve).